# Hyperref did not work properly when I reset the section-counter during the document

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, counters

Hyperref from the TOC bring me to the wrong part of the document when I RESET the section counter in each PART. -- When I click in the TOC on section 1 in part II, the hyperref brings to section 1 in part I. -- Is there a whay to handle this problem?

part I
 section 1
 section 2
 section 3
part II
 section 1
 section 2

etc.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phenomenon you describe will be produced when using

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

to manually reset the counter. Here's a simple document reproducing the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Test part one}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\clearpage
\section{First test section in part one}
\clearpage
\section{Second test section in part one}

\part{Test part two}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\clearpage
\section{First test section in part two}
\clearpage
\section{Second test section in part two}

\end{document}
```

Instead of manually resetting the counter for each part, do the resetting using `\@addtoreset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Test part one}
\clearpage
\section{First test section in part one}
\clearpage
\section{Second test section in part one}

\part{Test part two}
\clearpage
\section{First test section in part two}
\clearpage
\section{Second test section in part two}

\end{document}
```

`\clearpage` commands just for the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. -- the magic; "\makeatletter\@addtoreset{section}{part}\makeatother" solved my problem :) -- But in the meantime I also solved the problem myself with the "hypertexnames=false" in the "\usepackage{hyperref}" option-field. Again, thanks for your prompt answer!